# What is the "cluster" cron job?

Tags: cron, cluster, webmin

I understand that cron job is some task running automatically on unix-like OS. My server is ubuntu14.04 with webmin installed. I was trying to setup a cron job through webmin, there is this "cluster cron job" in the menu. 
I did a little search but couldn't get what I wanted. Could anyone please tell me whether this "cluster cron job" is what I am looking for? If yes, what role does this "cluster" play?

Comment: And you tried the docs? Because its pretty clearly spelled out there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Described here:

http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/Cluster_Cron_Jobs

A cluster cron job runs the same cron command on multiple defined servers.  So if you want to schedule something on more than one server at once, then it's what you're looking for.